# Do SNMP Informs guarantee that there is no loss?

Tags: snmp

I am working on a monitoring application, using [SharpSNMPLib](http://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/tutorials/v3-operations.html#inform-operation) on C#. I was using SNMP Traps but found out that there are some traps that are lost. Now I am using SNMP Informs.

Do you think that this counters the loss (because Informs are acknowledged traps), or is it pretty much the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the sender. For instance, if it is a fatal event, it is unlikely that the sender will be able to resend an unacknowledged event. In general, informs are more reliable than traps, but there is no guarantee that a sender *will* resend an unacknowledged inform, only that the sender *can* resend an unacknowledged inform.

This is how Cisco explains informs, [SNMP Inform Request](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/snmp/configuration/xe-3se/5700/snmp-xe-3se-5700-book/nm-snmp-inf-req-review.html):

> **SNMP Inform Request**
>
> The SNMP Inform Request feature supports sending inform requests. SNMP
>   asynchronous notifications are usually sent as SNMP traps.
>
> Traps are less reliable than informs because an acknowledgment is not
>   sent from the receiving end when a trap is received; however, an SNMP
>   manager that receives an inform acknowledges the message with an SNMP
>   response PDU. If the sender does not receive a response for an inform,
>   the inform can be sent again.

Comment: If I understood you well, you mean that if the inform is lost, it can be sent again, nevertheless there is no guarantee?

Comment: Correct. There is acknowledgement, but it is not like TCP where there is an actual two-way conversation set up which guarantees delivery.